# Hide ln: ./lnInclude in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I am using openfoam (a cfd solver) with ubuntu. when running applications installed with it for example "blockMesh", I use blockMesh > log.blockMesh to stock the log so it is not printed in the terminal, until here everything works perfectly.
since I wanted to use some basic calculation I was using inside the blockMeshDict, #calc, but since then even if I said to stock in a log file, the terminal is printing "    ln: ./lnInclude" several times, is there any way to hide this print in the terminal?
best regards,
franco

Comment: Perhaps these messages are going to standard error rather than standard output? what happens if you use `blockMesh > log.blockMesh 2>&1` instead?

Comment: yees it worked!!! thanks a lot, could you explain the function? either way it worked perfectly, thanks!